# Remove starting tags from an xml string in php

Tags: php, html, xml, web, extract

I have a URL like

```
http://lx2.loc.gov:210/lcdb?operation=searchRetrieve&recordSchema=marcxml&version=1.1&maximumRecords=10&query=bath.isbn%3D9781594634123%0A++++
```

which returns an xml string, now I want to remove the starting tags of this xml string and store the rest of the xml string in a variable.

```html
EDIT 0:

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Currently this is the xml string that is getting returned from the URL.

```
EDIT:1

    <record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
<leader>01618cam a2200385 i 4500</leader>
<controlfield tag="001">18265203</controlfield>
<controlfield tag="005">20160810164742.0</controlfield>
<controlfield tag="008">140812s2015 nyu 000 1 eng</controlfield>
<datafield tag="906" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
<subfield code="a">7</subfield>
<subfield code="b">cbc</subfield>
<subfield code="c">orignew</subfield>
<subfield code="d">1</subfield>
<subfield code="e">ecip</subfield>
<subfield code="f">20</subfield>
<subfield code="g">y-gencatlg</subfield>
</datafield>
<datafield tag="925" ind1="0" ind2=" ">
<subfield code="a">Acquire</subfield>
<subfield code="b">1 shelf copy</subfield>
<subfield code="x">policy default</subfield>
</datafield>
</record>
```

This is the desired result that i want to get stored in the xml variable in php.

Comment: You should've posted here xml structure (at least a sample) and desired result, what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of splitting it down to it's parts is...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://lx2.loc.gov:210/lcdb?operation=searchRetrieve&recordSchema=marcxml&version=1.1&maximumRecords=10&query=bath.isbn%3D9781594634123%0A++++");
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('zs', 'http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('def', 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim');

$nodes = $xml->xpath('//zs:record//def:record');
echo $nodes[0]->asXML();
```

The XPath fetches each record element, then you can convert each element to XML (I've only done this with the first one, usually a `foreach` would be better).

The registerXPathNamespace is being called twice, once to register the zs namespace, the second is for the default namespace in the inner record element.  Note that I'm using 'def' as the prefix to make it easier.  Then in the XPath expression, I'm using both these namespaces to select the inner record element.

Edit:
Adding the attribute...

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//zs:record//def:record');
$nodes[0]->addAttribute('type', 'local');
echo $nodes[0]->asXML();
```

As record is already the root - this creates...

```
<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" type="local">
  <leader>01618cam a2200385 i 4500</leader>
```

Comment: i did that .. it removed a couple of the tags from the xml , not whole . But i've  got no clue of how it's working. Can you help me remove all the unnecessary tags.

Comment: I've updated the code to limit it more, didn't realise the extra level was there.

Comment: hey . i was trying to add an attribute to the record tag , but its not working . but when i do it for the leader tag then it works .. can't figure out the reason.I am using this `  $xm1l->record->addAttribute('type', 'local');
`

Comment: Can't check it ATM as the system (lx2.loc.gov) isn't working, but you could try `$xm1l->record->addAttribute('type', 'local','');` as there is a default namespace (the third parameter is the namespace)

Comment: no .. it didn't worked .. It is giving this error `Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute(): Unable to locate parent Element`

Comment: Thanks .. it works like a charm . but i have a question why is the attribute name not accepting `:` . All the other special characters are working .